# window location href not working

Tags: javascript, redirect, web

I am trying to navigate to a new page using javascript. When I put window.location.href = "next.html" in the header of a page it works fine. but when calling it from a function after a button is clicked, it does not work. Example code:

```
function next(){
 $post = "?id=10"
        alert($post);
     window.location.href = "next.html" + $post;
 }
```

the alert displays ?id=10, but it does not redirect. Thanks for the help

The " missing was a typo and is not in the real site, sorry!

Comment: you're missing double quotes in $post...

Comment: You should fix your code sample, that would error out before reaching the alert.

Comment: even i can see your function is not properly made

Comment: Sorry! This is not the exact code in my site, just a recreation of it, with all the editing to the post var removed. the post is correct in the site code.

Comment: First, dont try to mix php and javascript

Comment: Which part of this is PHP? I was under the impression this is all javascript

Comment: `$post` ... $ is often used in php for variables this is why myself and im sure others were confused.

Comment: @JPatrickDev i will update my answer now !

Comment: @JPatrickDev see my edit at bottom of answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
function next(){
 $post = "?id=10
        alert($post);
     window.location.href = "next.html" + $post;
 }
```

Is a syntax error in your PHP. Try this:

```
<?php
    function next(){
     $post = "?id=10";
?>
     alert($post);
     window.location = "next.html" + <?php echo $post; ?>;
<?php
    }
?>
```

### **You really should not mix PHP with JavaScript like this how ever.**

---

**EDIT**: Ok after confusion has been cleared - if no PHP is involved try:

```
function next(){
 var post = "?id=10";
        alert(post);
 window.location = "next.html" + post;
 }
```

Comment: Nope,still doesnt redirect. I tried to make a function that just did window.location.href, and called it the same way I am calling the next() function, and that doesnt work either.

Comment: try `window.location = "next.html" + post;`

Comment: Nope, still doesnt work. Would testing locally instead of uploading to my webserver stop this from working?

Comment: No. show me the code as it is now, paste it  at http://www.paste.to/ and show me.

Comment: On the `onClick=` you need a return false:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="navigate(); return false;">Next</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a error in the code:

`$post = "?id=10` should have `"` in the end